# PHP MYSQL display table data from different id

Tags: php, mysql

[mysql tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aPTec.jpg)

How do I output product_price SUM of the selected product_id?

The current output is "1245". it seems to be working however it is placing "124" in front of the "5" The result I want is "5".

See the image for more details.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM product_list WHERE school_subject_product_id = '1'"; //<---- There are 4 products under this id

$result = $mysqli->query($query);
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        $product_id = $row["product_id"];
        $sql = "SELECT SUM(product_price) as total FROM products WHERE product_id = $product_id";
        $query = $mysqli->query($sql);
        $row = $query->fetch_assoc();
        $sum += $row['total'];
        echo $sum;
    }// end of while
```

Comment: put the echo $sum outside of the while?

Comment: Sorry, that was old code, I have removed it.

Comment: I suggest you initialize the `$sum` variable to `$sum=0` first, because you're using it right away such as your code `$sum += $row['total'];`

Comment: @Xun Thank you very much, that worked perfectly. such a simple fix yet i have been attempting to make it work for hours -.-

Comment: @Gian welcome, glad to help you. So you know why your previous output is 1245 now? haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place the `$sum` variable outside the loop so it won't repeat the recurring sum of your data